# Call daterangepicker onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I am using a date range picker (http://www.daterangepicker.com) and I want to call it using "onclick" how can I do that? Here is my code

```
    getDateRanges(function(dates) {

    $('input[name="start_date"]').daterangepicker({
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        locale: {
            cancelLabel: 'Clear'
        },
        isInvalidDate: function(date) {
            // Here use your dates that you've got from the server.
            var dateRanges = dates;
            return dateRanges.reduce(function(bool, range) {
                return bool || (date >= moment(range.start) && date <= moment(range.end)); 
            }, false);
        }
    });

    $('input[name="start_date"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        document.getElementById("start_date").value = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        document.getElementById("end_date").value = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    });

    $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $(this).val('');
    });

});
```

Currently it shows when `start_date` textbox is clicked, I want change the way it is shown by showing it on "onclick".

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for - are you wanting to show the datepicker when you click on a different element?

Comment: I just want to know how I can call the date range picker using the onclick function instead of how it is now.